# Where is the /etc/nginx folder?

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm getting a 413 Request Entity Too Large error when I try to upload a large image (~1MB) to my Laravel api. The solution everyone gives is to modify the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, but I can´t seem to be able to find that file. Where is it exactly located? I'm using Windows 10 and Laravel 6.8.

Answer (score 1):

"/etc/nginx" is for linux. In Windows maybe you are using Xampp (which uses Apache instead Nginx). You may not even be using Apache because you probably run the application with `php artisan serve`. I recommend you check php settings in for `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` (edit `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directives)

More info:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/413-request-entity-too-large

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/etc/nginx/` directory on windows because this is a path in Linux operating system, in windows you either have installed XAMP or WAMP for both of them you need to increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file, follow this [Article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size-in-php/) to change `php.ini` for XAMP and it's very similar to WAMP